# How to add buttons with independent click event

Tags: c#, runtime

I want to add buttons and textboxes dynamically on runtime with each
button react differently.

ie `newbutton1` linked with `texbox1 ,`newbutton2`linked with`textbox2`

Right now any button just prints from the first to the last textbox
one after the other.

Also consider that I have a button1 & textbox1 already on the form for guides

Here is my code :

```
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();

        int NumTextBox = 0;
        void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(textboxes[NumTextBox].Text);
            NumTextBox++;
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        void AddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                buttons.Add(newButton);
                newButton.Click += click;// 
               // newButton.Location.Y = button1.Location.Y + 20;
                newButton.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y+25+x);
                x += 25;
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);   

                TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
                textboxes.Add(newTextBox);
               // newTextBox.Click += click;

                newTextBox.Location = new Point(textBox1.Location.X, textBox1.Location.Y+25+y);
                y += 25;
                this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);

        }
```

Comment: Have you thought of a `Hashmap<Button, TextBox>`?

Comment: set the `newButton.Tag = buttons.count+1` before addign to the list, then in the click event get the textbox using the saved index like this `var txt = textboxes[Convert.ToIn32(((Button)sender).Tag)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone , **I followed @Franck's answer** .So **WHAT CHANGED** :

> I've deleted the pre-made `button1` & `textbox1` and add them
>   programatically on the `Form_load` so that I can add them in the
>   `Lists`

*A proof screenshot : http://prntscr.com/aprqxz*

**CODE:**

```
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();

        Button button1 = new Button();
        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var txt =  textboxes[Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag)].Text;
            MessageBox.Show(txt.ToString());

        }

        void AddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Click += click;
                newButton.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y+25+x);
                x += 25;
                newButton.Tag = buttons.Count;

                this.Controls.Add(newButton);

                buttons.Add(newButton);             
                //
                TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
                newTextBox.Location = new Point(textBox1.Location.X, textBox1.Location.Y+25+y);
                y += 25;
                this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);

                textboxes.Add(newTextBox);

        }
        void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                button1.Click += click; 
                button1.Location = new Point(55, 48);

                button1.Tag = buttons.Count;

                this.Controls.Add(button1);

                buttons.Add(button1);               
                //
                textBox1.Location = new Point(137, 50);

                this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

                textboxes.Add(textBox1);
        }
```

**EDIT 1:** As the counting starts from 0 I didn't added `newButton.Tag = buttons.count+1;` I added just `newButton.Tag = buttons.count;`

Answer (score 0):

you can have a class like mybutton that inherits from button class, in this new class you can have a property with textbox type . just like following code . and in your code when you want to  Instantiated Button you can use `list<mybutton>` and set linkedTextbox property with a textbox.

```
public class myButton:Button
{
   ...
   public TextBox linkedTextBox{set;get;}
}
```

and in your code you should write some thing like this :

```
list<myButton> buttons=new list<myButton>();
Textbox someTextBox=new TextBox();
buttons[0].linkedTextbox=someTextBox;
```

and in your event you can use:

```
((myButton)sender).linkedTextBox.text="Some thing";
```